# How to customize(Change design like color, font, images) of Google Chrome custom navigation

Tags: css, google-chrome

Hi I was displaying a confirm navigation when user closed my website like

[image]

I used below code to display custom navigation in my website

```
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var popit = true;
                window.onbeforeunload = function () {
                    if (popit == true) {
                        popit = false;
                        return "Are you sure you want to leave?";
                    }
                }
            });
```

Can anyone suggest me how to customize confirm navigation.

Comment: What you're seeing is a browser-specific dialog and it cannot be styled. Just see what it looks like in Firefox or IE.

Comment: Thanks for your response...

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to style these as they are Browser generated UI. If you want to be able to style a confirmation box or an alert then you will need to use the `<dialog>` element or some other method - note you will not be able to stop the browser from unloading like you can with and `alert` or `confirm`